# Excel VBA SUM function the range is misaligned

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I am trying to do a simple summation between cell A1 and A5. I tried recording this process using the macro, however, this is what i got:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-2]:R[4]C[-2])"
```

Naturally, i would think the range of the sum function would be:

```
R[1]C[1]:R[5]C[1]
```

as it represents cell A1 and A5. Is there any reason for this misalignment?

Thank you!

Miguel Valero

Answer (score 0):

The [] means that the formula is relative to the cell of the formula, so if your activecell is C1, RC[-2] means same row, the column offset by -2, so it is A1, R[4]C[-2] is then A5, the absolute formula is R1C1:R5C1, if you use =SUM($A$1:$A$5) and record it should show =SUM(R1C1:R5C1)